# setting timer between excel sheets 2013

Tags: excel, timer

There is multiple sheets in an excel document.
How do i set a timer that alternates between the sheets every five minutes?.
I'm not sure were to start with this because im not too familar with excel,is this even possible?

Comment: Do you just want the sheets presented on screen one at a time with five minute gaps, or is there to be any interaction between anyone and the excel workbook?

Comment: just one at a time,after 5 mins it will take you to the next sheet and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this code into a module in the VBA editor

```
Sub CycleSheets()
    While 1
        For Each thisWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If thisWorksheet.Visible Then
                thisWorksheet.Activate
                Application.Wait (Now + #12:05:00 AM#)
            End If
        Next thisWorksheet
    Wend
End Sub
```

You'll need to press escape a couple of times to break out of the loop.

Comment: how would i save this into a macro that can be used by other excel sheets?

Comment: @doe If you don't know how to save a macro you should not be running code you find online; if you can't read the code don't run the code. Try this for background: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-time-by-creating-and-running-macros-in-excel-2010-45c3e78e-9396-4476-967d-653174b5f7f3

Comment: @Gordan is there an other way that i can stop the loop,cause pressing the esc button isnt ver efficent

Comment: @doe you can add a modeless userform with a button, which would exit the code more elegantly but, as Grade 'Eh' Bacon suggested, it would be worth doing some background reading on VBA.